# How to make a REST call with json as parameter using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have googled a lot on this topic yet i could not found a simple example. All i need is a small demonstration of making a REST call using AngularJS in which we can pass JSON as parameter.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$http.post('path/to/api', jsonData).then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp.data);
});
```

This is shorthand for:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST', 
  url: 'path/to/api',
  data: jsonData
}).then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp.data);
});
```

Here are all the short hand methods available:

```
$http.head
$http.post
$http.put
$http.delete
$http.jsonp
```

**[See the docs here (click).](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)**

Comment: The second example is not equivalent to the first since you are not using jsonData.

Comment: @lucuma good call, I'm tired =D

Comment: thanks for the prompt response m59. would i need to parse json object into a flat file?

Comment: @Arjit That's up to you. I save the my data in a sql database. I use the json property names to figure out what the data is and where it belongs in a table. When asking the server for a json, I rebuild the json according to the request. The reason I don't save/retrieve jsons directly is because my data is relational. Some items, when deleted, need to delete others also, for example.

Comment: @m59 Thanks a lot. this portal is awesome. so many helping hands.

Comment: @Arjit No problem, just read over the docs next time. This question may eventually be deleted.